# Debug an already running app without restarting it

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

Is it possible to connect Eclipse to an already running app without restarting the app?

Comment: Trillion dollar question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to Debug an already running app without restarting it.

Steps

Just run your app, Go to devices select you device and then your already running app and then select debug option on the top of device window.
It will start debugging your app.

Comment: I think the easiest way to find it is in the DDMS perspective of eclipse.

Comment: How do you do this in Android Studio?

Answer (score 11):

**Eclipse**

1- Make sure you have the app's project code in Eclipse (you can't debug an app if you don't have its code).

2- Open DDMS perspective (Window > Open Perspective > Other > DDMS)

3- In the Devices tab select your device and expand if needed.

4- Select your application (you'll see the package name)

5- Click on the small bug icon next to the Devices tab to attach the debugger.

**Android Studio**

Click on the "Attach debugger" icon. It's the one on the right in the picture below.

[image: Android Studio icons]

Alternatively you can access this feature from Run > Attach debugger to Android process.

You will be presented with a dialog displaying connected devices and the running apps you can debug.

Select a process and click OK.

Comment: how do you do this in Android Studio ?

Comment: @CQM Go to help -> search for 'attach debugger to android process' -> then select the process you want to debug.